# How to page refresh on dialog cancel button in CQ5

Tags: aem

Can we write a listener to refresh the page when author hits the cancel button? I know this sounds a negative requirement but I want to know whether there is any out of box functionality there? Like we have afteredit, afterrender, afterremove in cqEditConfig

Answer (score 1):

Did you try overriding buttons with a custom handler function? An example is on the widget docs: http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Dialog

In practice this means you should create a `buttons` node in your dialog, and for each button -- a subnode with `text` and `handler` properties -- where `handler` is a JS function.